# Vue.js how to show image preview before update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

Hi i have my custom component where i am loading image. I need to show that image after i choose image and before i upload it on server. How to do this please? I tried use v-on:change effect on img tag but it is no working. My plan was use that test() function to doing that image preview.

```
<template>
    <div id="insert-component">
        <div id="insert-new" >
            <h2 class="text-md-left">New Category</h2>
            <div class="mt-2 text-left">
                <a href="#" id="img-button" class=" d-flex flex-wrap" v-on:click.stop="loadImage()">
                    <img src="/storage/images/no_image.png" alt="logo" v:on-change="test()">
                    <input type="file" class="d-none" id="load-category-image"  v-on:input="handleFileSelected">
                    <button class="btn btn-dark btn-block" >Pridať obrázok</button>
                </a>
                <small class="text-danger d-none error">Súbor musí byť png, jpg alebo jpeg</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block my-2" v-on:click="submit($event)">Pridať kategóriu</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "InsertComponent",
        props: [ 'updateTableData' ],
        data: function () {
            return {
                category_name: "",
                category_description: "",
                category_img:"/storage/images/no_image.png",
                file:null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            test(){
              alert("test");
            },
            loadImage(){
                document.getElementById('load-category-image').click();
            },
            handleFileSelected(event) {
                const acceptedImageTypes = ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'];
                let loadedFile = document.getElementById('load-category-image').files;
                if(acceptedImageTypes.includes(loadedFile[0]['type']))
                {
                    this.category_img="/storage/images/"+loadedFile.name;
                    this.file=loadedFile;
                }
                else{
                    let $errorsElements = document.getElementsByClassName('error');
                    for (let item of $errorsElements) {
                        item.classList.remove('d-none');
                    };
                    category_img="/storage/images/no_image.png";
                }
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `URL.createObjectURL(files[0])` generating url.

codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGYoyr